# Subtract two lists with a condition in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two lists for example for i=7 periods :

```
list1 = [0,0,16.5,0,29.7,62.7,90]
list2 = [0,0,0,0,10,12,2.5]
z = [0,0,1,0,1,1,1]
p[j] = [28,10,12,5,30,15,40]
rhs = 27
y = []
if z[j] == 0:
  y.append(0)
else
    if p[j] < rhs:
       y.append(0)
    else 
       y.append([a-b for a,b in zip(list1, list2)])

print(y)
```

The final results is y=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 19.7, 0, 50], however my code does not give that. Could you please help me to figure it out.

Comment: Can you clarify what your algorithm is supposed to be doing?

Comment: Neither `p` nor `j` is defined in your code. Please give a [mcve].

Comment: How do you `50`? `list1 - list2 == 87.5` for that index.

Answer (score 1):

`zip()` all the lists together:

```
>>> [a-b if c and d >= rhs else 0 for a, b, c, d in zip(list1, list2, z, p)]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 19.7, 0, 87.5]
```